# Getting dropdown to back back to normal when an item is clicked

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have the following script which works very will:

http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/uUAqe/

I just need to make a change to it so the the .navigation and .dropdown go back to normal when the .items is clicked.  Right now the .navigation and .dropdown only back back to normal when the .navigation is clicked again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add the code below:

```
$('.items').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggle();
  $('.navigation.active').removeClass('active'); 
});
```

You only need to add a toggle for the drop down related to the current item, and remove the class 'active' from the current navigation item.